# Add invoice status to order grid

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, collection, grid

We try to add the invoice status column to the sales order grid.

We added the code beneath to the prepareCollection function:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.parent_id',array('state'));
```

And the code beneath to the prepareColumns function:

```
$this->addColumn('state', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice Status'),
    'index'     => 'state',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('state'),
));
```

We got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_invoice.parent_id' in 'on clause'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - **be careful with joining live tables on your sales_order_grid** in the admin view. The reason is simple - any action or long-running query that your admins might be executing (for instance, sorting by a custom unindexed column with no other filters and 300k+ orders) may cause locks for your join table and prevent production orders.

Your column defines this as `type` of `options` but the option list you're providing is the entire invoice collection!!!

Out of the box, invoice `state` is only 1 of 3 potential values:

```
/**
 * Invoice states
 */
const STATE_OPEN       = 1;
const STATE_PAID       = 2;
const STATE_CANCELED   = 3;
```

So you can handle it one of two ways - explicitly state the options:

```
'type'      => 'options',
'options'   => array(
    '1' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Open'),
    '2' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Paid'),
    '3' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Canceled'),
),
```

Or, use something handy that Magento provides -- a static method for all invoice states in case they differ from version to version:

```
'type'      => 'options',
'options'   => Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::getStates()
```

I prefer the latter as I am not a fan of typing out array options manually :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sales_flat_invoice.parent_id` with `sales_flat_invoice.order_id`. Not sure if it will give you the desired result, but you won't get the error anymore. The reference to the order table is kept in `order_id`. `parent_id` does not exist.

Comment: The error is gone. Unfortunately the column values are still empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the invoice id in the sales order grid then you can use the following code in your prepareCollection() function as

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id', 'increment_id as invoice_id');
```

By using the following code you will able to get the invoice id from the current order id in sales order grid.
after this add column field as

```
$this->addColumn('invoice_id',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Invoice Id'),
            'align' =>'right',
            'type=' => 'text',
            'index' => 'invoice_id',
        )
        );
```

For more follow me on 
http://www.webtechnologycodes.com

Comment: its working but my filter is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('soa'=> 'sales_flat_invoice'), 'soa.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('soa.state'));

$this->addColumn('state', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('invoice Status'),
        'index'     => 'state',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'filter_index' => 'soa.state',
        'options'   => array(
        '1' || '3' => Mage::helper('core')->__('0'),
        '2' => Mage::helper('core')->__('1')),
        //'3' => Mage::helper('core')->__('cancelled')),
    ));
```